# Adding a banner to facebook webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, css, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a browser extension which when activated displays a banner on top of a web page. All code is complete the only problem that remains is with facebook and youtube.

I have used the following CSS to translate the entire content downwards after pre-appending the banner to the body tag.

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(100px)
```

The effects work fine but the blue facebook navigation bar does not remain visible when i scroll the web page. Here is a [video of the error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/15rzu37s9kwhsrg/error.mp4).

I tried adding the rule `position:fixed` but that did not work.

Comment: My guess is that it is against Facebook policies.

Comment: @WizKid I just want to manipulate the HTML. How can that be against policies. Please do elaborate

Comment: Websites usually don't like when you inject ads on them.